# Wizzair discount club no-show of club member

Tags: air-travel, return

I booked 6 return tickets using Wizzair discount club to complete the booking. During the booking it was said that you have to be a passenger in order to use Wizzair Discount Club. But now something came up and the membership holder cannot travel, both on the outbound as well as the inbound flight.

My question is whether the other traveler can still use the flight? According to the discount club rules, the discount club member should be part of the booking.

For the outbound flight, I'm sure this isn't a problem because the club member is part of the booking. However, is the discount club member still part of the booking for the inbound flight after missing the outbound flight?

If not, what are our options? When trying to remove the discount club member from the original reservation, Wizzair asks me to pay for this cancellation. Can the club member just no-show without problems? If not, should the other passengers part of the same booking just pay the difference between the discounted and normal price, or do they have to pay the current fare (which is much higher)?

Comment: Can one of them join Wizzair? It's like €30, or €70 for six people.

Comment: They could of course, but there's no option to do so as they didn't make the original reservation.

Comment: Yes, but I wonder if *adding a second member, then removing the first* would get a better response from the system / people.  Obviously it defeats the purpose of a buying club if you're just buying club-price tickets on behalf of random non-members. Assume the worst until you have an approved modified itinerary in your hands.

Comment: I have a similar situation, how did you resolve yours?